# How to hide the X button present at the top from the antd modal

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, react-typescript

How to hide the X button present at the top from the ant d modal, also how can I disable the behavior of closing the modal using ESC key

```
return (
<Modal
title={modalHeader}
okText="EXIT"
cancelText="CONTINUE"
visible={visible}
onCancel={onCancelHandler}
onOk={exitUser}
width={600}
cancelButtonProps={{hidden:isExFlag}}
>
<DescriptionParagraph>
{modalBodyText}
</DescriptionParagraph>
</Modal>
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/modal/) version `4.6.6`

to hide the X button present at the top from the ant d modal, use the prop `closable`

```
<Modal closable={false}>...</Modal>
```

to disable the behavior of closing the modal using esc key, use the prop `keyboard`

```
<Modal keyboard={false}>...</Modal>
```

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]